# Spring Batch And File Upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch project, this is the configuration of my Reader.

```
<bean id="personneReaderCSV" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" >
    <property name="resource" value="input/personne.txt" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
                <property name="names" value="id,nom,prenom,civilite" />
            </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="targetType" value="ma.ensa.Personne" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I want to use a file Upload with JSF to choose the file the I want Read data from, so how I can do it to make the value of the property resource dynamic. 
Help and Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to parameterize the input filename in your job by setting a property in the `JobParameters` of the job and then injecting it into your reader bean in this way:

```
<bean id="personneReaderCSV" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
   <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters[filename]}" />
   <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```

Please note that you should also add `scope="step"` to your bean.

This is called **late binding** and is illustrated in [§5.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#late-binding) of the official spring-batch documentation.

Comment: Thank's for improving my question. I didn't put attention to mistakes. Plus, english in not my native language.

Comment: My problem is that the name of the file is changed. Because I am working with managed Beans. I don't know if you understand my problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert about JSF... can you elaborate more what "the file is changed" means? Can't you execute your job once you are sure your file name won't change anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot update:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<CarInfo> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileLocation) {
    FlatFileItemReader<CarInfo> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileLocation));
    flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
    flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    return flatFileItemReader;
}
```

I hope you can have the Multipartfile either saved into the resource folder and share it as Resource or else find a way to pass that as resource object to the param list. Then get it injected here shown above